ESP32-S3 SD Card not working
I am trying to interface an SD card with my ESP32-S3 module. The code I am using as follows.
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"

#define REASSIGN_PINS
int sck = 40;
int miso = 39;
int mosi = 41;
int cs = 42;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(10);
  }

#ifdef REASSIGN_PINS
  SPI.begin(sck, miso, mosi, cs);
  if (!SD.begin(cs)) {
#else
  if (!SD.begin()) {
#endif
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();

  if (cardType == CARD_NONE) {
    Serial.println("No SD card attached");
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("SD Card Type: ");
  if (cardType == CARD_MMC) {
    Serial.println("MMC");
  } else if (cardType == CARD_SD) {
    Serial.println("SDSC");
  } else if (cardType == CARD_SDHC) {
    Serial.println("SDHC");
  } else {
    Serial.println("UNKNOWN");
  }

  uint64_t cardSize = SD.cardSize() / (1024 * 1024);
  Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);

  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  createDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  removeDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 2);
  writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "Hello ");
  appendFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "World!\n");
  readFile(SD, "/hello.txt");
  deleteFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  renameFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "/foo.txt");
  readFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  testFileIO(SD, "/test.txt");
  Serial.printf("Total space: %lluMB\n", SD.totalBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
  Serial.printf("Used space: %lluMB\n", SD.usedBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
}

I am constantly getting "Card not mounted". The SD card module is being supplied with about 3.215V. When I connect a logic analyzer, I'm not seeing anything off of the SPI lines. I'm sure I'm missing something minor but I'm not sure what it is.

Yes, that was what I meant to say.
